# Require "everything" from a node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, dsl, require

I'm writing a DSL, and I want to put everything from a required module into the current namespace to be able to write something like this

```
// I know it's not working.
// In python, I'd do: from mydsl import *
{*} = require('./mydsl');

node('London');
node('Paris');
edge('London', 'Paris');
```

Here are some versions I tried as a workaround

```
// In python: import mydsl as dsl
dsl = require('./mydsl');
dsl.node('London');

// In python: from mydsl import node, edge
{node, edge} = require('./mydsl');
node('London');

// Extend `this` with imported functions
_ = require('underscore');
_.extend(this, require('./mydsl'));
this.node('London');
```

Since my DSL has many keywords, using `{node,edge,...} = require` would be clumsy.  I'd prefer a solution that can be ported to the web with browserify.

Comment: downvoter, please, leave a comment about your reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using `with`?

```
var mydsl = require('./mydsl');
with (mydsl) {
    node('London');
    node('Paris');
    edge('London', 'Paris');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very very very **BAD** practice.

```
_ = require('underscore');
_.extend(global, require('./mydsl'));
node('London');
```

Comment: that's why I'd do `_.extend(local, require('./mydsl'))` if a `local` object were available